# Can I buy stock of a company that just IPO

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy, stock-markets, ipo

I'm a college student, and I wonder if I can buy stock from a company right after it finishes its IPO?

To be more specific, I'm interested in the IPO of Alibaba, which hasn't happen yet.

If I am not allowed to buy its stocks immediately after they go on sale, how long do I have to wait?

And also who are allowed to buy the stocks at the first minute they are on sale?

Comment: If you couldn't buy them, it wouldn't have been a **Public** Offering.

Comment: Super Bowl Final tickets are also public offering.@MSalters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could buy a stock on the day of its IPO.

> I'm a college student, and I wonder if I can buy stock from a company
>   right after it finishes its IPO?

Yes, you can. However, unless you are friends or family of an employee, chances are you'll be paying a higher price than you think as there is generally a fair bit of hype on most 
IPOs that allows some people to "flip them" which means someone is buying at a higher price.

> If I am not allowed to buy its stocks immediately after they go on
>   sell, how long do I have to wait?

Generally I'd wait until the hype dies down as if you look at most historical IPOs the stock could be bought cheaper later but that's just my perspective.

> And also who are allowed to buy the stocks at the first minute they
>   are on sell?

Anyone but keep in mind that while an IPO may be priced at $x, the initial trades may be a few times that value and the stock may come down over time. Facebook could be an example to consider of a company that had an IPO at one price and then came down for a little while on its chart over the past couple of years.

Comment: But note that you can't buy the stocks _at the IPO price_ after the IPO. You will have to pay the market price, which will probably be considerably higher. As a small-scale private investor, there's basically no way for you to buy stocks at the IPO price for most IPOs.